# Translate search operators in jqGrid on the fly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

Our application has its own translation facility and since jqGrid translations are not complete we are injecting the translations into jqGrid on pager setup.

We are using jqGrid 4.4.4 - updating is currently not an option.

This works fine for almost all translations (see alerttext, etc in the example below).

However for the search filter operators (see odata array below) this does not work at all.
The odata strings ("equals", "not equal",...) are not replaced with the translated strings. 
As said, using the standard jqGrid language files is not an option for us.

Does anybody know how to inject the translation for search operators on the fly?

```html
jQuery("#displayresponses").jqGrid( 'navGrid', '#pager',
        {
            add: false,
            edit: false,
            del: true,
            alertcap: sWarningMsg,
            alerttext: sSelectRowMsg,
            searchtitle : sSearchTitle,
            refreshtitle : sRefreshTitle,
            deltitle : sDelTitle,
            search: true,
            refresh: true,
            view: false,
            position: "left"
        },
        {}, // edit options
        {}, // add options
        {
            msg : strDeleteAllConfirm,
            bSubmit : sDelCaption,
            caption : sDelCaption,
            bCancel : sCancel,
            width : 700
        },
        { // Search options
            caption : sSearchCaption,
            Find : sFind,
            multipleSearch: true,
            odata : [ sOperator1, sOperator2, sOperator3,
                sOperator4, sOperator5, sOperator6,
                sOperator7, sOperator8, sOperator9,
                sOperator10, sOperator11, sOperator12,
                sOperator13, sOperator14 ],
            Reset : sReset,
            width: 700
        }
        
    );
```

Comment: Do you have **different** translations in different grids on the page of you have *common* texts for `odata`? To answer your question, it's important to know **which version of jqGrid you use and from which fork of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7)**? Which language you use? It could be probably good to fill the translation for your language and to include the correct texts in jqGrid code? I develop free jqGrid fork and can include your texts.

Comment: I see now that you added [free-jqgrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) tag to your question. I tried to use `odata` parameter and I had no problem in overwriting the texts. Could you include the demo or at least more full code, which demonstrates the problem? I repeat my suggestion to modify the language file and to include by default correct translated texts in the corresponding `grid.locale-XX.js` fils.

Comment: We are using the old jqGrid 4.4.4 - it does not seem to work with that version.

Comment: **The version 4.4.4 is dead since a long time**. You use ["free-jqgrid"](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) tag, which means that you use free jqGrid fork of jqGrid, which I develop. The first version of it was 4.8.0. The current version is 4.13.2. I use 4.x.y version numbers because I try to hold the compatibility with old versions. You can try (temporary) to change 3 lines of your code to use free jqGrid 4.13.2 from CDN (see [the wiki](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use wrong tag [free-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) tag to your question, which follow to misunderstandings. The [free-jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/free-jqgrid/info) tag should be used in case of usage [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) existing in versions 4.8.0, ... 4.13.2.

The retro version 4.4.4 use `$.jgrid.search.odata` as the parameter of `jqFilter` instead of `odata` option introduced later. Thus you have to change `$.jgrid.search.odata` "on the fly".

**The old version 4.4.4 is dead** and I would strictly recommend you to upgrade to the current free jqGrid 4.13.2. You can use it directly from CDN like it's described in the wiki atricle and additionally included in the README of all last published versions of free jqGrid. If you would do prefer to use NuGet package then you can uninstall old [jQuery.jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.jqGrid/) package and install [free-jqGrid](https://www.nuget.org/packages/free-jqGrid/) instead.

Comment: Can you please give an example of how I would "change $.jgrid.search.odata "on the fly". ?

Comment: @Deckard: You should describe more clear what you mean under "on the fly". Where? When? Depend on which criteria? The changing of `$.jgrid.search.odata` is *global* on the page. Do you have many grids on the page where you could need to have *different* values for `$.jgrid.search.odata` or one changes for the page will be enough? I can continue...

Comment: @Deckard: For example `$.jgrid.search.odata[0]` contains `'equal'` `$.jgrid.search.odata[0]` contains `'not equal'` and so on. You can change the values and the searching dialog will use the modified values. You can use `recreateFilter: true` searching option (near other options like `multipleSearch: true`) if could change the values *after* the user opened the searching dialog at the first time.